# Reference type read-only properties - Really?

Tags: c#

In my DDD pattern, I am exposing SqlConnection read-only property to my DAL class object. But as SqlConnection is reference type, I can still call .Dispose() method eventhough it's read-only.

The same thing happened to List<> which I resolved by converting it to ReadOnlyCollection but I happen to use many other core .NET reference type object as read-only property and cannot afford to create wrapper class.

Any resolution?

**Added code:**

```
public class DbContext
{
    public SqlConnection sqlConnection {get; private set; }
}

public class caller
{
   public caller()
   {
       var dbContext = new DbContext();
       dbContext.sqlConnection.Dispose(); // Want to hide Dispose() method
   }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should show with (pseudo) code what you're trying to achieve since it's not clear at all.

Comment: *Why* does your class need to expose an instance of SqlConnection?

Comment: Read-only property means you can't reassign it, not that you can't mess with the value it references.

Comment: Don't expose the connection.

Comment: Even if you did manage to hide `Dispose()` when you access the property directly, if your property is an `SqlConnection`, there is nothing preventing the caller from passing it to some other method that takes an `SqlConnection` parameter, and having that other method call `Dispose()`.

Comment: Not that it's a good idea (because not disposing an object once you're done with it is bad), but if you really want to prevent from calling the Dispose method, you would have to create a new class with a SqlConnection private field, create every member you need to use in this class, and implement those members by using members from the SqlConnection field.
`public IDbCommand CreateCommand()
{
    return sqlConnectionField.CreateCommand();
}`

Comment: I got you guys. May be I have to rethink the way I designed DbContext class and shouldn't expose the sqlConnection. Thanks you all for your support. I could have mark one of the above comment as answer. :-P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `readonly` modifier only applies to the reference, not to the actual instance (being referenced).

```
class Foo
{
    public readonly Bar Bar1;
    public Bar Bar2 { get; } 
    ...
}
```

You can still say `f.Bar1.Prop = 1;` but because of the `readonly`  you can't do `f.Bar1 = null;` . The same for Bar2.